# Two Select computed Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I try to binding two computed select with Knockout:
 - the first select(DropDownLinee) is filled when on page load
 - the second select(DropDownCorse) is filled when the user select an item on the first select

This is the example:

```
<select id="DropDownLinee" data-bind="options: ArrayLinee, optionsText: 'NomeLinea', optionsValue: 'NomeLinea', value: selectedLinea " data-toggle="dropdown"></select>

<select id="DropDownCorse" data-bind="options: ArrayCorse,  optionsText: 'CodiceCorsa', optionsValue: 'CodiceCorsa', value: selectedCorsa " data-toggle="dropdown"></select>

 function LineeViewModel() {
      var self = this;

  self.selectedLinea = ko.observable();
  self.selectedCorsa = ko.observable();

  self.ArrayLinee = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.ArrayCorse = ko.observableArray([]);

  $.getJSON('/Home/GetLines', function (data) {
    self.ArrayLinee(data);
  });

  self.ArrayCorse = ko.computed(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Home/GetRides',
    {
      LineaSelezionata: self.selectedLinea(),
      DirezioneSelezionata: $('input[name=radio4]:checked', '.areaselezione').val()
    },
    function (data) {
      debugger;
      self.ArrayCorse(data);

    });
  });
}


  lineeVM = new LineeViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(lineeVM);
```

I have this error when i check to load the 'DropDownCorse':
Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem???

Thank in advance greetings Donato

Comment: Computed functions are used to compute values based on other values and does not have write.  You have defined `ArrayCorse` as computed and inside it, you are setting it. This is causing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables), not a `computed`.

```
  self.selectedLinea.subscribe(function (newSelection) {
    $.getJSON('/Home/GetRides',
    {
      LineaSelezionata: newSelection,
      DirezioneSelezionata: $('input[name=radio4]:checked', '.areaselezione').val()
    },
    function (data) {
      debugger;
      self.ArrayCorse(data);

    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is what I wanted. I tried the example that you have suggested and it works.

Comment: Also a major flaw in this function is that it will re-trigger an AJAX request if the user hesitates and changes the first select twice to the same selection. Better would be to have a flag somewhere that checks whether the data has been fetched already (although this was also a problem in the original code, it hasn't been corrected here).

Comment: @Tyblitz Re-selecting the same value doesn't trigger a subscription. Only an actual change does.

Comment: @RoyJ there will be an actual change: although it is unlikely, a user may 1) select A, 2) select B, 3) reselect A.

Comment: @Tyblitz Sure, that can happen. Optimization by caching results is pretty far beyond the scope of this question, though. The embedded jQuery is a more immediate problem.

Comment: Yes, the embedded JQuery was only for example it has been replaced by an observable object.